# Save value to each column python

Tags: python

I have the code like this:

```
Max = 0.0
while True:
    value = float(input("Please input a number: "))
    if value > Max:
        Max = value
        print("Max is ", Max)
    else:
        date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print("Max is ", Max)
        with open("test.csv", 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
            writer.writerow([date,Max])
            print("Write Max value to file success",[date,Max])
        break
```

The current result will save date and Max value in the same cells.
I want the result to have the header and will be save like this:

```
Colum A             Column B
Date_time           Max_value
03/01/2019            5.0
04/01/2019            6.0
05/01/2019            7.0
......               ....
```

How can I do it?

Comment: can you show what you are getting right now?

Comment: currently, I have the result like this "2019-12-04 15:20:15 3.0" It is the same cell

Answer (score 0):

CSVs consist of (as the name suggests) comma separated values -- which means you need to make sure that you enter a new row in the correct format. The decisive line in your code is the following:

```
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
```

With the delimiter set to `\t` you actually get lines separated by tabs. My suspicion is you're expecting a comma separated line, i.e. the following change should hopefully make it work:

```
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
```

As `delimiter=','` is indeed the default value, you can achieve the same result my leaving out the delimiter attribute from the function statement.